# Prevent VirtualBox Guest from Delivering Cached Files

Tags: virtualbox

After editing files in my development environment and saving them to my guest OS (CentOS), the Guest delivers a cached version of the edited files (.css or .js).

At first I thought this was a local browser caching issue, but I've deleted, disabled, incinerated, etc every local cache in all 4 browsers and in the laptop (non-host) hard drive.

In addition, I tested using a machine (that has never accessed the guest) and the guest still delivered the unedited files.

I've then disabled all caching modules in Apache - I'm pretty sure (but not positive - and open to any suggestions) Apache is not the culprit.

Either my guest or my host is caching files somehow/somewhere and I can't figure out how or where.

This has been a very frustrating 48 hours - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Background:

- VirtualBox v 4.0.12
- Guest: CentOS 5.5/LAMP (Being used as a local development server) Internal IP 192.168.12.62
- Host: Windows Server 2008 (Network Config: Bridged) Internal IP 192.168.12.42
- Development files are stored on the Host and shared with the Guest via "Shared Folders"
- Application development is done on a third machine (laptop) connected to the host via mapped network drive. Internal IP 192.168.12.32
- I've configured Apache with numerous virtual IP's 192.168.12.150-180
- Please let me know if I've left anything out.

Comment: I don't think this issue is related to being virtual server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298933/shared-folder-in-virtualbox-for-apache/6511441#6511441

Comment: Definitely VBox related.  See answer.

Answer (score 19):

This [forum post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33201) confirms the problem.  Here's the [bug report](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/819).  Vboxsf doesn't play nicely with `sendfile`.  The Apache workaround, as [previously mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298933/shared-folder-in-virtualbox-for-apache/6511441#6511441):

```
EnableSendFile Off
```

For the curious, here's the [SendFile docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#enablesendfile).

Comment: Awesome. This still happens and the fix works like a charm, vbox 4.2

Comment: As of 5.1.2 this still appears to be the case. Fix still works.