# How to clear cached javascript files using chrome as browser and nginx as webserver

Tags: google-chrome, angularjs, caching, nginx

I am running localhost the following [code](https://github.com/simkimsia/ng-book/tree/master/examples/http-api-server2)

What happens is that my browser/server appears to cache the outdated javascript file in js folder.

I have cleared my browser cache and turn on disable cache when devtools is on.
But the app.js continues to be outdated copy.

Am I supposed to do something to the nginx server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out why.

I am using VirtualBox and I needed to turn off the sendfile configuration.

See this for more details:
[Prevent VirtualBox Guest from Delivering Cached Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921670/prevent-virtualbox-guest-from-delivering-cached-files)

Just make sure for the relevant conf file inside the /etc/nginx/sites-available you explicitly say

```
sendfile off;
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting expires -1; in your nginx location rule for js files.

Comment: I am surprised by this answer. Is this necessary?