# nginx not serving updated static files

Tags: nginx

Switching from apache to nginx, and encountering something weird.

1) Say I have a file yo.txt in the document root of my site and it contains 'foo'.

`curl http://localhost/yo.txt => 'foo'`

2) then I alter the file to contain 'bar'

`curl http://localhost/yo.txt => 'foo'` (still!)

If I remove yo.txt, I get a 404.  If I remove all the text, I correctly get an empty file when I curl the url.

I checked the last modified HTTP header after I modify the file, and it is correct, even though the contents of the file are stale.

I'm using the standard configuration from nginx after an apt-get install nginx.

what gives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant/VirtualBox/Apache2 Strange Cache Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479117/vagrant-virtualbox-apache2-strange-cache-behaviour)

Answer (score 15):

I'm using Vagrant. Setting `sendfile` to `off` in `nginx.conf` fixed the problem as found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/269420/disable-caching-when-serving-static-files-with-nginx-for-development), e.g."

```
sendfile off;
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer - so glad I found this, was experiencing a VERY strange behavior with static files until disabling `sendfile`.

Comment: I like magical solutions, but anybody knows why and how this fixes the problem?

Comment: This is a [work around for a known problem with old versions of VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479117/vagrant-virtualbox-apache2-strange-cache-behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked:

```
    expires modified 10y;
```

According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires):

> The time in the “Expires” field is computed as a sum of the current time and time specified in the directive. If the modified parameter is used (0.7.0, 0.6.32) then the time is computed as a sum of the file’s modification time and the time specified in the directive.

Comment: Well, nice answer. But pretty useless as long as it is not clear where (which file, where in file) to put `expires modified 10y;`