# BrowserSync + Gulp with Vagrant not refreshing

Tags: gulp, vagrant, browser-sync

I'm using BrowserSync with Gulp to live reload a site in a local machine when specific kinds of files are changed. I've the following snippet in my `gulpfile`:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browsersync.init({
        proxy: "mySite:8080",
        files: ["./*.html", "dev/*.css"]
    });
});
```

When changing (and saving) any of the above kinds of files, I get an output like this in my terminal:

```
[BS] Serving files from: ./
[BS] Watching files...
[BS] File changed: index.html
[BS] File changed: dev\styles.css
```

All the while, the site reloads as expected, but its content does not reflect the changes that were made. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here. Any hint appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that my host machine is running Windows 10 and my guest machine is running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. The VM provider is VirtualBox.

Initially, I was using the default `config.vm.synced_folder` method. I had this on my `vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Path/To/My/Host/Website/Folder/", "/usr/nginx/html/mywebsite/"
```

I've since tried using NFS, with the following configuration:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Path/To/My/Host/Website/Folder/", "/usr/nginx/html/mywebsite/", 
:type => :nfs, 
:mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1']
```

Since my host is running Windows, I installed the plugin [vagrant-winnfsd](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd), which adds support for NFS. But now vagrant halts when it tries to mount the NFS shared folder.

In addition, since I was getting the following error on `vagrant up`: `GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.16) and guest (4.3.36) do not match`, I installed the plugin [vagrant-vbgues](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest), in order to keep VirtualBox Guest Additions up to date. At no avail either. Vagrant is still freezing when it tries to mount the NFS shared folder.

Comment: See my updated answer about `rsync`. The `vagrant-vbguest` plugin is hit and miss for me as well, but if you ssh into the machine you can manually install guest additions if you feel it is an issue. With `rsync` for synced folders, I have not had an issue with versions mismatching between 4.2 and 5.x, for what it's worth.

Comment: Thanks, will look into that!

Comment: Related: [nginx not serving updated static files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12864947/55075), [Vagrant/VirtualBox/Apache2 Strange Cache Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9479117/55075)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It so happens that the problem was related with VirtualBox, as explained [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#virtualbox). Since I'm running Nginx on a virtual machine in VirtualBox, the solution to my problem was to comment out the `sendfile` directive in `nginx.conf`, or simply set it off, like this:

```
sendfile off;
```

The same issue is reported [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/269420/disable-caching-when-serving-static-files-with-nginx-for-development), and [here](https://jeremyfelt.com/2013/01/08/clear-nginx-cache-in-vagrant/). As well as in the Vagrant [docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/virtualbox.html), which state that "There is a VirtualBox bug related to `sendfile` which can result in corrupted or non-updating files."

Answer (score 1):

The title and the tags say you're using Vagrant, even though it's not mentioned in your question.

Make sure your changes are being synced to the VM. Have a look at the [vagrant documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) to select the type of synced folders that will work for your situation. Their basic example is as follows:

> ```
> Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
>   # other config here
>
>   config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/srv/website"
> end
> ```

You can `vagrant ssh` and check the files manually to make sure they match, and that the synced folders are working as expected.

**UPDATE**

Based on the new information and comment, I would recommend using `rsync` as the shared folder method.

```
config.vm.synced_folder "Host/Path/", "/Guest/Path", type: "rsync",
    rsync__exclude: [ '.git', 'logs'],
    rsync__args: ["--verbose"],
    rsync__chown: false
```

I have never found a way to make NFS play well (and perform well) if Windows is in the mix.

Comment: Initially, I was using a similar configuration, but I'm now exploring NFS. Will try your suggestion to check files manually though as I didn't try that before. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I returned to the initial configuration and checked files as per your suggestion, with `vagrant ssh`. The weirdest thing is happening: the index.html, for instance, reflects the changes that I make on my editor. Could it be that browser-sync is watching the correct file, but refreshing some other file?

Comment: A quick note about rsync: it won't work in Vagrant 1.8.0 (due to a bug that is not fixed in 1.8.1 yet). There is a workaround for this though. It is reported [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6702).