# Apache is changing the contents of a file being served

Tags: apache, virtualbox

This has been driving me crazy.

Somehow when ever apache serves the following file:

```
$().ready(function(){
    hideDataSetSelection();
    var selector = "select#interface";
    alert($(selector + "").val());
});
function hideDataSetSelection(){
    $("div#dataBtn").hide();
}

function showDataSetSelection(){
    $("div#dataBtn").show();
}
abc
xyz
123
456
```

It actually outputs the following:

```
function hideDataSetSelection(){
    $("div#dataBtn").hide();
}

function showDataSetSelection(){
    $("div#dataBtn").show();
}

$().ready(function(){
    hideDataSetSelection();

    var selector = "select#interface";
    alert($(selector + " option:selected").val());
al
```

Which actually has content from a 'previous' version of the file.
This seems to occur for files that end in `js` or `json` only. Depending on the contents of the file, the output will get scrambled. I can only imagine that Apache is caching the file incorrectly or something...

This is within a Virtualbox environment.

Any ideas what the cause of this issue might be?

Comment: This might even be cached in your browser. Have you verified that the request actually reaches your server?

Comment: Yes I've done a hard reload, a separate wget as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has been solved by turning off sendfile. It seems the same issue has been described here: 
[Vagrant/VirtualBox/Apache2 Strange Cache Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479117/vagrant-virtualbox-apache2-strange-cache-behaviour)