# Always use sendfile with nginx on Linux?

Tags: linux, nginx, sendfile

The nginx HTTP server has a [directive named `sendfile`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#sendfile), which can tell it to use the [Linux `sendfile()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) to do I/O without copying to an intermediate memory buffer. That should increase the I/O rate and reduce memory use. If you are running on a modern Linux system with a modern version of nginx, does it have any disadvantages?

---

In the *past* the directive could be problematic, for example [on VirtualBox VMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479117/vagrant-virtualbox-apache2-strange-cache-behaviour), hence my qualification of *modern* installations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @DanilaVershinin's answer: [Nginx documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#enabling-sendfile) recommends it for efficiency, except for large files. What can occur is that large file transfers can block connections overlong. The solution, found at the same link as above, it to use `sendfile_max_chunk`. Example:

```
location /mp3 {
    sendfile           on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 1m; # Limits chunks to 1 Megabytes
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would not use it for serving large files, for which you'd use [directio](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#directio) instead. Although NGINX already does disable it for you in that case.