# Apache caching javascript assets?

Tags: javascript, apache, caching, garbage

Not so long ago I was having trouble with javascript assets. When I made changes to them they wouldn't take effect and the file would become invalid javascript (firebug throwing errors and warnings).

I noticed that my changes weren't appearing and special characters were being added to the end of the file. A bit more digging and I noticed that the special characters were exactly the number of characters of my edits.

Original code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert('what');
});
```

Adding a line, should looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert('what');
     alert("what's going on?!);
});
```

Renders like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert('what');
});��������������������������
```

When I researched I found that modifying apache config's `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and commenting out `EnableSendfile off` fixed the issue.

### However...

Now the issue has returned, but apache config hasn't changed.

Please help. My current work around is renaming the file, viewing the new file and naming it back; this annoys me tremendously.

I'm developing on a vagrant box, CentOS 6, PHP 5.3/apache 2 - the original solution can be found here: [Shared folder in VirtualBox for Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298933/shared-folder-in-virtualbox-for-apache).

Unfortunately this no longer seems to work.

Comment: Have you checked for invisible characters like windows line breaks? tabs / spaces?

Comment: Yes, the file is clean. Only new changes are converted to these special characters.

Comment: You could use some cache busting like `<script type='application/javascript' src='somefile.js?v=somefileversion'></script>`. But since I am inexperienced with apache you may want to wait for a better suggestion.

Comment: Prusse - cache busting doesn't work, it seems to be the way the file is served up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant/VirtualBox/Apache2 Strange Cache Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479117/vagrant-virtualbox-apache2-strange-cache-behaviour)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often when `EnableSendfile On` causes breakage, EnableMMAP causes similar issues. Try turning that off too. You mentioned that you're using CentOS in Vagrant but not the host OS. Is it Windows perchance?

Comment: You're my hero. That fixed it right up! Host machine is Mac OSX.