# Apache + Centos 6.6 caching javascript

Tags: javascript, apache, vagrant, virtual-machine, centos6

I have the same problem as discussed here: [Apache caching javascript assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826596/apache-caching-javascript-assets?newreg=73a113e50ffe416c88323c55dfcc78a5). but, in my case, the problem persists.

Host windows 8.1

Vagrant Guest: Centos 6.6 32bits

I had uncommented those lines in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off
```

Restart Apache

But the issue persists.

My changes weren't appearing and special characters were being added to the end of the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

**Problem:**
I was editing my files with sublimetext2 from windows *host* and saving those with *Windows line endings*
Then linux *guest* served js files with wrong ending

**Solution:**
I changed lines ending to unix in sublimetext2
[Fixing Sublime Text 2 line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899843/fixing-sublime-text-2-line-endings)

Thanks